# Cannot read property of length undefined

Tags: javascript, json, rest, parsing

I'm using a dexi.io robot to automate extraction from permit databases. The robot will accept custom javascript to parse the incoming JSON object.

This code appears to work in some cases  - correctly parsing the incoming JSON - but fails in almost every circumstance. The error is cannot read property of length undefined.

Here's the test api that works: https://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People

Here's the code:

```
var people = JSON.parse(json).value;
var arr = [];

function getCountry(member) {
    try {
        return member.fields.name;
    } catch(err) {
        return "";
        }
}

for (i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    var member = people[i];
    var obj = 
        {
            "name": member.name,
            "Country": getCountry(member),
            "alias": member.alias
            };
    arr.push(obj);
}

return arr;
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of JSON that it's failing on?

Comment: I've found the problem. It was a navigation issue within the JSON. the .value in the first line was replaced with the correct path within the JSON and it started working instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Check your first line where is "json".I think you didn't defined a json file from which you are getting data.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are doing to fetch the response, but I was able to get this working pretty easily:

```
fetch("https://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  var people = data.value;
  var arr = [];
  function getCountry(member) {
      try {
          return member.AddressInfo[0].City.CountryRegion;
      } catch(err) {
          return "Country Info Not Available";
          }
  }
  
  for (i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
      var member = people[i];
      var obj = 
          {
              "name": member.FirstName,
              "Country": getCountry(member),
              "alias": member.alias
              };
      arr.push(obj);
  }
  
  console.log(arr);
});
```

Maybe this will give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the json from the given url. So, in your code the properties like 'member.name', 'member.alias', 'member.fields.name' doesn't exist.
Try using the exact property names from the json:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/$metadata#People",
  "@odata.nextLink": "https://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People?%24skiptoken=8",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.id": "http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People('russellwhyte')",
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"08D817F8EC7DAC16\"",
      "@odata.editLink": "http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People('russellwhyte')",
      "UserName": "russellwhyte",
      "FirstName": "Russell",
      "LastName": "Whyte",
      "Emails": [
        "Russell@example.com",
        "Russell@contoso.com"
      ],
      "AddressInfo": [
        {
          "Address": "187 Suffolk Ln.",
          "City": {
            "CountryRegion": "United States",
            "Name": "Boise",
            "Region": "ID"
          }
        }
      ],
      "Gender": "Male",
      "Concurrency": 637285705159912400
    }
  ]
}
```

What I am trying to say is that use the names exactly in json like 'member.UserName', 'member.AddressInfo[0].Name' etc.

Comment: I've got it figured out. Thanks for your help.